# Trigger php file from javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a file 'data.php' that handles incoming posts, updating and reading from a database. The posts comes every second.

And I have a file 'demo.php' with js script, the idea is that I want to present the data from the database in a graph. ..so it has to update every sec or so. How can i do that, do i need to trigger the php file someway to get new data to the js variable?

data.php:

```
<?php
     include "k_connect.php";
     if(isset($_POST['value']))
     {

        $amp_f = number_format($_POST['value'], 2);
        $amp = explode('.', $amp_f);
        $d_tid = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $amp =str_replace(",","",$amp);
        $tid = explode(' ',$d_tid);
        $tid = str_replace(":","",$tid);

        mysql_query("UPDATE impdata SET amp=$amp[0]
        WHERE ID=1");
      }

      $tid_back=array();
      $amp_back = array();

      $x=0;
      $SQL = "SELECT * FROM impdata";
      $result = mysql_query($SQL);
      while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $amp_back["amp"] = $db_field['amp'];
        $tid_back["tid"] = $db_field['tid'];    
        $amp_s =  $amp_s . json_encode($amp_back) . " ";
        $tid_s = $tid_s . json_encode($tid_back) . " ";
        $x++;
      }
```

?>

demo.php:

```
  function graf() {
       var amp = <?php echo json_encode($amp_s); ?>;
       var power = amp.split(":");
       alert(power[1].match(/\d+/g));
       var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
       setTimeout(graf, 500);
  }
  graf();
```

I get the right value in demo.php('power' holds it), but just one time, it  it doesn't  update, it is just the same value, dho if i hit f5 i get a new value.

My idea was :  'data.php' runs every time there is a post (every sec) and then the value of '$amp_s' is updated, that way my js function updates as well because it reads the value of '$amp_s'(setTimeout(graf, 500)).

Is there anything wrong with the way I put it up?

I have this in demo.php of course:

```
include "k_connect.php";
include('data.php');
```

Comment: have you tried jquery-ajax ??

Comment: or XMLHttpRequest if you prefer it without jQuery? (I would use jQuery)

Comment: Why dont you try to make a jquery/js function that makes ajax call and set timeout of 1 sec for that function. On Ajax page, you can fetch the data frm database and show it.

Comment: Trigger the php file someway? I think there is some basic understanding problem where which code runs and when.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to include `data.php` in `demo.php` like so:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/javascript');

include('/path/to/data.php');
?>
function graf() {
   var amp = <?php echo json_encode($amp_s); ?>;
   var power = amp.split(":");
   alert(power[1].match(/\d+/g));
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   setTimeout(graf, 500);
}
graf();
```

Then you can call the javascript just as you would normally `<script type="text/javascript src="demo.php"></script>`. Also, depending on if `$amp_s` is defined in a function, then you would have to declare it as a global variable.